# Remove UNIQUE keys from all columns

Tags: mysql, unique-key, alter

Is there a query to remove all `UNIQUE` keys from every columns? I'm not asking for doing it to every particular column because I just need a straight forward query to remove from all columns instead of altering and dropping the key from one column.

Comment: there's `alter table disable keys`, but that kills all of them, not just uniques.

Comment: That won't help, I need to remove unique keys not disable all keys.

Answer (score 0):

There is no special command that would remove all unique keys, but you can read information from the `information_schema`.`KEY_COLUMN_USAGE` and generate 'ALTER TABLE  DROP INDEX ' statements.

Note, KEY_COLUMN_USAGE contains information about all constraints (primary, unique and foreign keys), so to skip foreign keys, use query with WHERE condition, for example -

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, CONSTRAINT_NAME FROM information_schema.key_column_usage
WHERE REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA IS NULL;
```

...to omit primary keys from result set use this condition -

```
WHERE ... AND CONSTRAINT_NAME <> 'PRIMARY'
```